# Connecting Fifos (Client/Server Program)

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to make a simple client/server program, and learning how to work with Fifos along the way.

The program creates a fifo (FifoServer__) and blocks when opening, which is expected. However, when I open it from the other end, it also blocks! I looked at couple of examples and tried many things but I could not figure it out.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

```
//header.h


# include <stdlib.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <errno.h>
# include <signal.h>
# include <stdarg.h>

#define fifoServer "FifoServer__"
```

server.c:

```
# include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int serverfd;
    int client_pid;

    if (mkfifo( fifoServer, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP) == -1) {
        perror("could not mkfifo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        

    serverfd = open(fifoServer, O_RDONLY); //It blocks right here.
    if (serverfd == -1) {
        perror("failed to open fifo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        

    //Signal handeling
    if (signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Could not Ignore SIGPIPE. Error: %d\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //listening for connections requests (client's pid)
    while (1) { 
        if (read(serverfd, &client_pid, sizeof(client_pid)))
                printf("Client's pid: %d", client_pid);
        break;
    }

    // Unlinking and cleaning Fifoserver__
    close(serverfd);
    unlink(fifoServer); 
    remove(fifoServer); 

return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
# include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int serverfd;
    int client_pid;

    client_pid = getpid();

    serverfd = open(fifoServer, O_WRONLY);   //It blocks right here
    if (serverfd == -1) {
         perror("failed to open fifo");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (write(serverfd, &client_pid, sizeof(client_pid)) == -1) {
        perror("Could not open Client Fifo Writer. Error: %d\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Success !\n");
    close(serverfd);
    unlink(fifoServer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this write-up about non-Blocking I/O http://cr.yp.to/unix/nonblock.html

Comment: What error?  Generally people need specifics to help you diagnose issues.

Comment: At which line? Which filed descriptor is it complaining about?  Please try to anticipate and obviate the next obvious question(s).

Comment: Also Google all the relevant/appropriate man pages for your *NIX platform and read them carefully/thoroughly particularly germane to the issue you're having.  And a Google search should yield plenty of tutorials that show how to do exactly you're doing, since it is one of the most basic common things a UNIX developer needs to do (basic client/server).  I know because since I don't do this stuff often enough to remember all the details, I google them myself. Consider using fork() and socketpair() and see if you can squeeze client and server into one program, if it's not a huge amount of code.

Comment: I spent all day trying and looking up this issue up.
I tried many things, and non of them worked.

I'm sorry for being a pain but I have no where else to go seek for help besides books and man pages.

Comment: http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/netguide/dusockD.socketpairs_codetext.html  ... http://www.cis.temple.edu/~giorgio/old/cis307s02/readings/socketpair.c

Comment: Why do you  want fifos out of curiosity? They're a hassle. I did an API implementation using fifo's for a server and multiple instances and sending status back and forth. When processes die it's a hassle to figure it out, and delete them and prevent the sender from reading back its own message if the other side gets stuck or dies.

Comment: They aren't a huge mystery. Unless you have a specific need for FIFOs it will probably suffice to simply know the concept and use another well documented approach such as I've shown.

Comment: Finally, in order to proceed helping you debug your app, I asked you which line you got the bad file descriptor method so I could focus on that.

Comment: OK, putting non-block strategy on hold for a second, really? The original problem is it blocks on open?

Comment: Yes, it blocks from the server side for reading. And when I open the client side, it blocks for writing. So it blocks both sides.

Comment: That's what fifes do by default. But your comment says one of the open() calls blocks. THAT is a problem and points to a problem in your system not in your code. open() should not block.  By default FIFOs block. If you write a message to one that write will hang until something reads it, and vice versa. If the read gets there first it will block until something writes it. Normally someone would have a loop running in a separate thread in each process that writes, and reads and dispatches commands, respectively and pass status.

Comment: You *could* make a named FIFO so it gets an entry in the file system and then from one shell window use echo or cat to send data to it and in another shell window use cat to read data from it. You'll see how they behave that way and can experiment.

Comment: I recommend first try playing with named fifo creating it and playing with it from the command line.  It will make it more obvious why the code is doing what it's doing. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156

Comment: You were right, it was a problem with the system I was using.
I used another system and things start to work out nicely.

Thank you so much for your help and your patients in getting newbies wheels spinning. 

Best of all